# random number without using seed C programming

Tags: c, random

Is there any way to generate a random number in C without using seed.

Here what have so far but it still using srand(time(NULL)); which is a seed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h> /* required for sqrt() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* required for rand() */

int gen_rand();   /* note these are declarations of functions */

void main()
{
   int number;
   srand (time(NULL)); /* everytime you run program, it will give you different result */

   number = gen_rand();

   printf("%d is the power of 2 of %.0lf\n", number, sqrt(number));
}

/* Function generates random number power 2 of 20 - 230 */
int gen_rand()
{
   int n;
   n = rand() % 211;  /* n is random number in range of 0 - 210 */
   n = n + 20; /* n is now in range of 20 - 230 */
   return(n*n); /* return n to the power of 2 */
}
```

Comment: I think, if you don't call `srand()`, the seed will always be the same. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: You can use the rand function without setting the seed, but it will for every run of your program return the same sequence of "random" numbers.

Comment: So you want a real random number instead of a fake one, is that your question? As far as I know, you need extra hardware for that (basically a Geiger counter). Can you elaborate why you need a random number generator without seed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you don't seed the automatic number generator, it will behave deterministically and yield the same numbers every time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. 
There are basically two methods to get even remotely random numbers in c.

1) have a pseudo random number generator with seed -- that is an algorithm, that produces some sequence of numbers using clever arithmetic operators and possible lots of internal variables that are mixed, permuted, twisted and whatever. The seed can be implicit (i.e. always zero and each time you run the program, the same sequence is generated). Or it can be explicit, where the seed can be changed somehow between runs.

2) Using *external* source of data, that somehow changes in between runs. That could come from a *timer*, environment variables (program id perhaps), noise from camera, mouse movements etc.

1+2) use the external source of noise as seed to pseudo random number generator.

Comment: In some sense the internal state of the PRNG is a seed and that can be stored in a file between runs.

Answer (score 1):

All non-hardware based PRNG require some form of random input to combat their deterministic nature, thus a seed will always be required.

You can try abuse `/dev/rand` under linux (but it also is a PRNG), or if you have a very modern Intel CPU, their new [digital RNG facilities](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-digital-random-number-generator-drng-software-implementation-guide) would work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Generating random numbers by using the `rand()` function without using a seed will give you the same set of random numbers though.